# How to combine header files with data files with python?

Tags: python

I have separated files, one part are files only contained header info, like the example shown in below:
～content of "header1.txt"～

```
a 3
b 2
c 4
```

～content of "header2.txt"～

```
a 4
b 3
c 5
```

～content of "header3.txt"～

```
a 1
b 7
c 6
```

And another part are files only contained data, as shown below:

～content of "data1.txt"～

```
10 20 30 40
20 14 22 33
```

～content of "data2.txt"～

```
11 21 31 41
21 24 12 23
```

～content of "data3.txt"～

```
21 22 11 31
10 26 14 33
```

After combined the corresponded data files, the results are similar with examples in below:

～content of "asc1.txt"～

```
a 3
b 2
c 4

10 20 30 40
20 14 22 33
```

～content of "asc2.txt"～

```
a 4
b 3
c 5

11 21 31 41
21 24 12 23
```

～content of "asc3.txt"～

```
a 1
b 7
c 6

21 22 11 31
10 26 14 33
```

Can anyone give me some help in writing this in python? Thanks!

Comment: This just needs a single command: `cat header$i.txt data$i.txt > asc$i.txt`

Comment: are they both in the same folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want it in Python, here is the way to do

```
for i in range(1,4):

    h = open('header{0}.txt'.format(i),'r')
    d = open('data{0}.txt'.format(i),'r')
    a = open('asc{0}.txt'.format(i),'a')

    hdata = h.readlines()
    ddata = d.readlines()
    a.writelines(hdata+ddata)
    a.close()
```

Of course, assuming that the number of both files is 3 and all follow the same naming convention you used.

Comment: Thank you very much. But actually i have bunch of head files and data files separately, and they didn't name in systematically as file names shown here. So if there any good way to add files which name is irregular?

Comment: How many do you have of these head and data files?...May be if the number if not quite big with make like a dictionary of their file names, {head1:data1, head2:data2...etc}, then we can add them together.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (written in python 3.4 idle). Pretty long but should be easier to understand:

```
# can start by creating a function to read contents of
# each file and return the contents as a string
def readFile(file):
    contentsStr = ''
    for line in file:
        contentsStr += line
    return contentsStr

# Read all the header files header1, header2, header3
header1 = open('header1.txt','r')
header2 = open('header2.txt','r')
header3 = open('header3.txt','r')

# Read all the data files data1, data2, data3
data1 = open('data1.txt','r')
data2 = open('data2.txt','r')
data3 = open('data3.txt','r')

# Open/create output files asc1, asc2, asc3
asc1_outFile = open('asc1.txt','w')
asc2_outFile = open('asc2.txt','w')
asc3_outFile = open('asc3.txt','w')

# read contents of each header file and data file into string variabls
header1_contents = readFile(header1)
header2_contents = readFile(header2)
header3_contents = readFile(header3)

data1_contents = readFile(data1)
data2_contents = readFile(data2)
data3_contents = readFile(data3)

# Append the contents of each data file contents to its
# corresponding header file
asc1_contents = header1_contents + '\n' + data1_contents
asc2_contents = header2_contents + '\n' + data2_contents
asc3_contents = header3_contents + '\n' + data3_contents

# now write the necessary results to asc1.txt, asc2.txt, and
# asc3.txt output files respectively
asc1_outFile.write(asc1_contents)
asc2_outFile.write(asc2_contents)
asc3_outFile.write(asc3_contents)

# close the file streams
header1.close()
header2.close()
header3.close()
data1.close()
data2.close()
data3.close()
asc1_outFile.close()
asc2_outFile.close()
asc3_outFile.close()

# done!
```

By the way, ensure that the header files and data files are in the same directory as the python script. Otherwise, you can simply edit the file paths of these files accordingly in the code above. The output files asc1.txt, asc2.txt, and asc3.txt will be created in the same directory as your python source file.

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful. But actually a bunch of head files and data files, and  they didn't name in systematically as file names shown here. So if there any good way to add files automatically instead do it manually? Like using loop procedure etc..

Comment: @King-Zhao: It is possible to add files automatically using a loop. In fact, this is demonstrated in the other answers below. However, since you are trying to deal with files of irregular filenames, at some point you will need a way to map each data file to its corresponding header file. You could use a configuration file read by your program on each run. The configuration file can be a simple text file containing names of a header file and its corresponding data file. This way, your program can combine the correct header file and data file even with irregular filenames.

Answer (score 0):

This works if the number of header file is equal to the number of data files are equal

```
#Glob is imported to get file names matching to the given pattern 

import glob
header=[]
data=[]

#Traversing through the file and getting the content

for files1 in glob.glob("directory/header*.txt"):
    a=open(files1,"r").read()
    header.append(a)

for files2 in glob.glob("directory/data*.txt"):
    a1=open(files2,"r").read()
    data.append(a1)

#Writng the content into the file

for i in range(1,len(data)+1):
    writer=open("directory/asc"+str(i)+".txt","w")
    writer.write(header[i-1]+"\n\n"+data[i-1])
    writer.close()
```

**Edit**

This method will only work if they are in different folder and there should be no other files other than header or data file in that folder

```
#Glob is imported to get file names matching to the given pattern 

import glob
header=[]
data=[]

#Traversing through the file and getting the content

for files1 in glob.glob("directory1/*.txt"):
    a=open(files1,"r").read()
    header.append(a)

for files2 in glob.glob("directory2/*.txt"):
    a1=open(files2,"r").read()
    data.append(a1)

#Writng the content into the file

for i in range(1,len(data)+1):
    writer=open("directory/asc"+str(i)+".txt","w")
    writer.write(header[i-1]+"\n\n"+data[i-1])
    writer.close()
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But actually i have bunch of head files and data files separately, and they didn't name in systematically as file names shown here. So if there any good way to add files which name is irregular?

Comment: Sure,  they are in separated

Comment: Failed, need 15 reputations